# Firewall threat protection rules for SSH/SFTP

Tags: ssh, firewall, azure, sftp, azure-networking

Can a firewall improve the security of an SFTP service through inspecting incoming requests (e.g. to block any SSH commands which aren't required when only using SFTP?

### Context

I recently found a VM in our estate which has a public IP for exposing SFTP (i.e. SSH; not FTPS) and an HTTPS service to the internet.

I'm looking to put the web site behind the Azure App Gateway, having that perform SSL offloading, then routing the request to the backend VM internally over HTTP.

Since the SFTP and HTTPS services share the same hostname, I'll have to point that at the Azure Firewall then route requests on port 22 to the VM, and requests on 80/443 to the app gateway (requests on 80 will just get an HTTP 301 redirect to the HTTPS endpoint; those on 443 will be routed to the backend as described above).

Since we're putting a firewall between the public and the VM it would be good to use it to further improve security... Already it will only forward on port 22 to the VM, so that's a win (e.g. blocking RDP), and it gives us options like client IP whitelisting (though for our use case that's not wanted as we could have legitimate connections from anywhere).

However I'm wondering if there's anything like the OWASP rules for the app gateway's firewall uses for HTTP, which could inspect the SSH traffic and block anything that looks suspect.

My guess is that there isn't since SSH will use RSA encryption with keys known only by the VM and client; not the firewall... but I've not delved too deeply into SFTP/SSH so there may be options I've not thought of which would further improve the solution's security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK - no. You can't inspect `ssh` traffic and filter commands.

What you can do is to filter the IPs which can connect to port 22 to this machine. And you can do it using Azure Network security groups. Check [this document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/network-security-groups-overview) about details around security groups.